# 403 Error For Web Service Call

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services, windows-server-2008-r2

I am using a 3rd-party tool that runs as a Microsoft Service on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.  The machine is using a Dell SonicWall firewall.  The tool has defined ports that it is listening on of which I have opened one.  Using an external web tool that port is listed as open.  The service has been installed and shows as running when I run services.msc.

Everything runs great on my local machine.  However, when I try to query the service I get a 403 error. The following is what the query URL looks like:

https://{siteUrl}:{portNumber}/scanservice/v2/getstatus?method=jQuery111106758983342442662_1428439579840&_=1428439579841

This is an AJAX GET request coming from an ASP.NET MVC application.

The code attempts to find an open port by querying 3 ports that are the https ports for the service.  The first two are ports that I have not opened on the machine. These queries time out which is what I would expect.  The last port is the one I have opened on the server.  I immediately get a 403 error.

Is there somewhere where I need to expressly allow that service, not just the port?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: 403 sounds more like the service is denying access than a firewall issue. Can you provide some details about the service?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for the info.  First post.

Comment: @faester  That is one of my concerns too.  The service is the Captiva Cloud Capture Toolkit 2.0.  I am using the evaluation version of the software and I have considered the possibility that it blocks requests that are not from localhost.  I have posted in their support forums but I don't expect much.  I am going to try to get them on the phone if possible too.  Barring that, are any considerations to be made if the website is secure (https)?  I am admittedly lacking in my knowledge of the SSL. If the request URL has https but is going to a port that isn't 443 is there further configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It is a case where your public IP is not whitelisted on the web service hosting server